# Create many to many relationship View in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am creating a web application and I am using Visual Studio 2019 as a development software.

Technical specification: ASP.NET CORE(v3.0), Entity Framework Core, SQL Server

I have table Name: User and Role in both table UserId and RoleId is the primary key respectively.

To manage user wise role I have table name UserRole(Join of two tables) in that one user can have multiple roles like Deep is also admin and also the staff. I have created this table. In that, I also set both as a primary key.

For add, I need to make a view like from dropdown admin can select a user as Deep than there checkbox list or multi-select dropdown for role selection.

**Model**

***UserRole.cs***

```
 public class UserRole
    {
        public int UserId{ get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual IList<User> User { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
        public virtual IList<Role> Role { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to create a controller from the model than it throws an error of complex type. I have also try with `[ComplexType]` above the model class name.

Can anyone please look into this and let me suggest what should I have to do on the database or code side?

Comment: You should not use the EF models for your API/view models. There are many reasons for this - one of which you have discovered in that the foreign key relationships lead to infinite loops when serializing the object. Map the EF model to a DTO and use this in the Controller to return your data.

Comment: Thanks @strickt01 For the reply. Can you detail out your suggestion I can't get your point?